# Yahoo pipes: Replace an item in a RSS feed

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I'm having a problem with Yahoo pipes.

I'm trying to get the url which is located at the end of the item.title (RSS feed)
I want to use that url in item.link

I use a Regex to get the url (((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+) and that works fine.

But how can i use this to use it for item.link?

Now it looks like this:

```
..
<item>
<title>
Hello this is a test http://www.google.com
</title>
<link>
http://otherurl
</link>
<description>
Hello this is a test http://www.google.com
</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">
http://otherurl
</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 24 Jan 2012 18:27:18 +0000</pubDate>
</item>
..
```

And I want to make it like this:

```
..
<item>
<title>
Hello this is a test http://www.google.com
</title>
<link>
http://www.google.com
</link>
<description>
Hello this is a test http://www.google.com
</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">
http://otherurl
</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 24 Jan 2012 18:27:18 +0000</pubDate>
</item>
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Regex module](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Regex) to copy `item.title` to `item.link` an then modify `item.link`:

1) In `item.link` replace `.*` with `${title}`

2) In `item.link` replace `".* "` (without quotes, note the space at the end) with `""` (empty)

Comment: Tnx, for the quick response. I can now copy the whole item.title to item.link, but how can I extract only the url (step 2 you provided)? I can give you the pipe: [link](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f02b441f7afeed3563bbc90fa7034f1f)

Comment: The problem with the regex is that i can find and select the url, but I can't extract it. First I do a: RENAME item.description copyas linkje. Then a REGEX item.linkje replace (((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+) with $1. However I still got the whole sentence and not only the url. How can I change the code so I can only display the url?

Comment: Added a regex to extract the URL. Note: only works for the simple case "Some text with spaces http://example.com"

Answer (score 0):

I found it! It should be

```
^.*(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+).*$
```

it will select everything until it founds a url!